# Is Windows Service an ideal replacement of a VB 6 exe deployed as a scheduled task?

Tags: vb6, windows-services

There is an existing VB 6 exe which is set as a scheduled task (running every 20 minutes) on a Windows server. The client now wants it to replace with a .NET component. 
Is writing a Windows Service (with timer implemented) an ideal solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need to keep state information between invocations, I would just keep it simple and leave it a scheduled task.  This gives you the scheduling and basic logging for free.

I have about 20 .Net console apps running as scheduled tasks like this.

Comment: +1 on the scheduling for free. Windows' Task Schedule is quite powerful, you'd be hard pressed to re-implement it correctly.

Comment: Agreed. If you ever need to show any type of user interface (either to report information to or extract information from the user), a service is emphatically not an option. Works fine with a scheduled task, though.